# PC restarts without error message

Tags: desktop-computer

guys, I'd really love it if you guys could help me out.
I built myself a new PC a few days ago.
The specifications:
Ryzen 7 3700X
MSI B450 -A Pro Max
NZXT Kraken x62
2TB Intel  660p
Asus Rog Strix RTX 2080 TI
2x 16GB XPG Spectrix D60G 3200MGhz
Corsair CX 750 Watt

Comment: You need a lot more detail in your question.  Are there error logs?  What have you tested?

Comment: What do you see in the Event Viewer, in the System section, right before and after the restart?  EventID 41 Kernel-Power indicates an unexpected power loss, probably a loose cable.

Answer (score 0):

As this is home-built, I would start by checking for loose connections - re-seat every cable and component (memory, cards, etc).

Next, I would suspect overheating. How soon after powering up does this occur? Is it always 'very soon after' or does it vary? Could it be related to ambient temperature? I would run the system with the 'lid' (side panel) off, and observe. Make sure all the fans are spinning. After this, I would suspect the CPU heatsink. Did you apply thermal compound, and did you do a good job of applying it correctly, and did you then attach the CPU heatsink according to instructions? Applying the 'right amount' of thermal compound is somewhat hard to judge, and sometimes tightening down the heatsink onto the actual CPU heat spreader is not easy to get right. If you've assembled hundreds of home-built PCs, this is less likely to be a problem but you don't say.

How far does the machine progress during it's boot process before this happens? Are you making it all the way into the OS, or is the restart occurring very quickly and not even making it to the OS? If you are getting into the OS, which OS are you using? And even though you say 'no message', what about log files? Assuming a Windows PC, the event viewer may contain clues.

Are you able to get into the BIOS before the restart occurs? BIOS access is often (but not always) achieved through a specific key press at a specific time during the boot cycle.

Typically, with home-built PCs, there are jumpers (or switch-blocks) to set on the motherboard to allow for different configuration options. Are you sure these are all correct, if you have any jumpers?

I realize these are simply more questions than answers but I feel we need more information before we can really 'answer'.